# Why is document.getElementById not working?

Tags: javascript, html-table

```
document.getElementById('r'+a.toString()).innerHTML+="<td><tr>"+a+"</tr>X<tr>"+n+"</tr>=<tr>"+a*n+"</tr></td>";
```

I can't create my table using `getElementById().innerHTML` and `<table><td
r+a></td></table>`. The code above is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide your HTML too, so that we are able to help you.

Comment: You have `<tr>` tags within a `<td>` tag. That is not valid HTML. It should be the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Use console log to see if your element even exists and was found. 
If the code doesnt work then most likely
1) the element was not found
2) your element id string is not what you think it is.

```
let elementId = 'r'+a.toString();
console.log('element id is:', elementId);//<- what is the elementId
let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
console.log('element is:', element);// <- did you find the element
element.innerHTML+="your html here";
//was there an error in console.
```

I dont know exaclty what you want to achive, but a simple multiplication table can be made like this.

```
//  HTML
<section>
  <p>Multiplication table</p>
  <button onclick="createTable()">Create Table</button>
  <input type="number" value="3" id="size" placeholder="number of rows">
  <table id="multiplication-table"></table>
</section>
// CSS
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 1em;
}
// JavaScript
window.createTableRow = function(rowNr, size) {
  let row = '<tr>';
  for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    row += '<td>' + (rowNr * i) + '</td>';
  }
  return row + '</tr>';
}
window.createTable = function() {
  let size = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
    let table = document.getElementById("multiplication-table");
  table.innerHTML = '<tbody></tbody>';
  let i;
  for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    let row = createTableRow(i, size);
    table.innerHTML += row;
  }
}
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/xpvt214o/500777/

Comment: can you please help me for making a mulitplication table of 3 using getelementbyid.innerELEMENT and making a <table> tag in the innerHTML ... please sir I am learning.